# flatten objects of array mongodb $project

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection called patient - that contains hundreds of documents, where each document represents 1 person. Each document contains many arrays - where an array represents a category of information about the patient. Example here - showing root level info (_id, EnrollmentID) and 2 arrays: imaging and health state.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5be32372ca69786f080f36a1"),
    "EnrollmentId" : 1234,
    "imaging" : [
        {
            "EnrollmentId" : 1234,
            "CR_ImagingXRay" : "1 Time",
            "CR_ImagingCT" : "1 Time",
            "CR_ImagingMRI" : "1 Time",
        }
    ],
    "health_state" : [
        {
            "EnrollmentId" : 1234,
            "CR_DateAssessmentCompletion" : "14-Jan-16",
            "CR_HealthState" : 55.0
        },
        {
            "EnrollmentId" : 1234,
            "CR618_DateAssessmentCompletion" : "27-Apr-16",
            "CR618_HealthState" : NaN,
            "CR_CR618HealthStateChange" : NaN
        },
        {
            "EnrollmentId" : 1234,
            "CR12_DateAssessmentCompletion" : NaN,
            "CR12_HealthState" : NaN,
            "CR_CR12HealthStateChange" : NaN
        },
        {
            "EnrollmentId" : 1234,
            "CR24_DateAssessmentCompletion" : "8-Jan-18",
            "CR24_HealthState" : 85.0,
            "CR_CR24HealthStateChange" : 30.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to use the aggregation pipeline to create a new document with only specific elements of the primary document. I wrote this query:

```
db.patient.aggregate([
    {
        $project: 
            {_id: 0, EnrollmentId: 1,
             CR_HealthState: '$health_state.CR_HealthState',
             CR618_HealthState: '$health_state.CR618_HealthState',
             CR12_HealthState: '$health_state.CR12_HealthState',
             CR24_HealthState: '$health_state.CR24_HealthState'
            }},
   {
        $out: "test"
   }
   ])
```

That gives this output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bec716cb75cface16e9e88c"),
    "EnrollmentId" : 1234,
    "CR_HealthState" : [
        55.0
    ],
    "CR618_HealthState" : [
        NaN
    ],
    "CR12_HealthState" : [
        NaN
    ],
    "CR24_HealthState" : [
        85.0
    ]
}
```

I desire a 'flat' output like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bec716cb75cface16e9e88c"),
    "EnrollmentId" : 1234,
    "CR_HealthState" : 55.0,
    "CR618_HealthState" : NaN,
    "CR12_HealthState" : NaN,
    "CR24_HealthState" : 85.0
}
```

I am new to mongodb - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: But it's an array! Arrays are meant to store "lists of things". So okay sure the named properties "happen" to be unique across all the elements, and you could "brute force" this with a `$mergeObjects`, but really this is just **bad design**. If you intend to access the data this way then it really should be changed in the structure of how it is stored. Then you would not need an aggregation pipeline statement slowing things down at all.

Comment: I do see that you are attempting to restructure this data, but your purpose is not really that clear. The main concern here is the one thing clearly shown in each array member is `"CR_DateAssessmentCompletion"`. Now those are different dates making them valid for "different entries". What you are asking for combines properties from different dates in a way that therefore does not make much sense. At the very least some more explanation here might make your purpose clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are projecting an element in an array, the projection itself is an array, as you observed. To avoid this you could use $arrayElemAt and reference the first element of the array, the 0 index. See below:

```
{'$project': {'EnrollmentId': 1,
             'CR_HealthState': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$health_state.CR_HealthState', 0]},
             'CR618_HealthState': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$health_state.CR618_HealthState', 0]},
             'CR12_HealthState': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$health_state.CR12_HealthState', 0]},
             'CR24_HealthState': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$health_state.CR24_HealthState', 0]},
            }},
```

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I was after - thanks.